# Using setTimeout() to delay YouTube from appearing on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-api, settimeout

What I want to do is use `setTimeout()` to delay YouTube a few seconds from appearing on the screen until after the cover is clicked.

The cover gets clicked, then for YouTube to appear 1,3,3,4 seconds after.

How it works now is, after you click the cover, YouTube appears right away.

I want to use `setTimeout()` to set a time when YouTube appears on the screen after the cover is clicked.

How would I be able to do this?

code https://jsfiddle.net/84wLe702/

```js
const load = (function () {
  "use strict";

  function _load(tag) {
    return function (url) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        const element = document.createElement(tag);
        const parent = "body";
        const attr = "src";
        element.onload = function () {
          resolve(url);
        };
        element[attr] = url;
        document[parent].appendChild(element);
      });
    };
  }
  return {
    js: _load("script")
  };
}());

(function manageCover() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
    document.querySelector(".curtain").classList.add("slide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    const thewrap = cover.parentNode.querySelector(".container");
    hide(cover);
    show(thewrap);

  }
  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());


const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  "use strict";

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
  }
  let hasShuffled = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    const shufflePlaylist = true;

    if (!hasShuffled) {
      player.setShuffle(shufflePlaylist);
      player.playVideoAt(0);
      hasShuffled = true;
    }
  }

  function addVideo(video) {

    const playlist = "M7lc1UVf-VE";

    new YT.Player(video, {

      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 0,
        controls: 1,
        loop: 1,
        rel: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        cc_load_policy: 0,
        fs: 0,
        disablekb: 1,
        playlist
      },
      events: {
        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function init(opts) {
    load.js("https://www.youtube.com/player_api").then(function () {
      YT.ready(function () {
        addVideo(opts.video);
      });
    });
  }
  return {
    init
  };
}());

(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function initPlayer(wrapper) {
    videoPlayer.init({
      video: wrapper.querySelector(".video")
    });
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.parentElement;
    show(wrapper);
    initPlayer(wrapper);
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}

.curtain-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.curtain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
}

.container {}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 8s;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);
}

.panel-right {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.video-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}

.video-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.wrap,
.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="tcell">
    <div class="curtain-wrapper">
      <div class="curtain-ratio-keeper">
        <div class="curtain">
          <div class="container">
          </div>
          <div class="video-wrapper">
            <div class="video-ratio-keeper">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="video video-frame">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-left">
          </div>
          <div class="panel-right">
          </div>
          <div class="jacket" title="Play" style="width:22%; height:auto;">
            <svg class="play" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
              <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                        M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your `setTimout` in `initPlayer` function, like

```
function initPlayer(wrapper) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    videoPlayer.init({
      video: wrapper.querySelector(".video")
    }
  )}, 4000);
}
```

Comment: How would I write it without the arrow function, using the equivalent to that?